# is this is the right way to use prefetch_related?

Tags: python, django, database, django-orm

i have these models

```
class Theme(models.Model):
    name = models.charfield()

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.charfield()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.charfield()
    .........

class MstProduct(Product):
    category = models.ForeignField(Category, related_name = 'category_products')
    themes = models.ManyToManyField(Theme, related_name='theme_products')
    .........
```

i want to fetch categories and there related products by

```
Category.objects.prefetch_related('category_products').select_related('category_products__themes')
```

is this is the right way to do this?

Comment: `Category.objects.prefetch_related('category_products__themes')`

Comment: what if it was Category is another object and i want also to fetch the category field in MstProduct,
would it be something like this:
DifferentObject.objects.prefetch_related('products__themes','products__category')'

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using something like below mentioned query:

```
Category.objects.prefetch_related('category_products', 'category_products__themes')
```